# My javaScript code is causing IE to time out but works on Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code that detects when a radio button is clicked in a form and then clicks a "Next" button.  The form is multi-page wizard style.

It works fine in Chrome and Firefox but it causes IE to time out with a Not Responding error when I click the radio button there.

Here's the code:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#UL_24').on('click', function() {
    var $form = $(this).closest('form');
    $form.find('.gform_next_button').click();
  });
});
```

Here's a JSFiddle of the HTML and JS together: http://jsfiddle.net/zpjyndd6/1/

Note that the redirect upon click works in this JSFiddle.  It just goes to a page not found because I'm using a relative URL within the form action.

I just tested this JSFiddle in IE and the redirect actually works in this.  So I'm guessing there is something outside of this code that is blocking it within IE.  Not sure why it still works in Chrome and Firefox though.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

The code in the JSFiddle might look a little off because I used a Chrome Extension to grab the block of HTML and related CSS from within a larger page.  It changed the names of some of the IDs automatically and did some other strange things.  It shouldn't impact this question though.

Comment: Please post the HTML and possibly a jsfiddle so we can test.

Comment: Please include the html code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I read your code, looks like you have messed up little with HTML. Anyway that is a different problem.

Try using .trigger('click') instead of .click().

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I just changed that within the JSFiddle and it stopped redirecting upon click.

Comment: Nevermind, it's working now.  I made that switch and it works fine in Firefox and Chrome.  It's still freezing up when I make the click within IE.